# How can I improve UICollectionView efficiency?

Tags: ios, performance, memory, uicollectionview, memory-efficient

I have an iOS app in which there is a collection view that that can have up to a couple hundred cells in it. Each cell has 5 views in it, 4 UILabels and 1 UIImageView. When I run the app normally the app uses absurd amounts of memory whenever I scroll through a couples of rows. As in about 5Mb of memory for 3 rows. I tried removing all the code in the cellForItemAtIndexPath such that the collection view controller looked like this:

```
    #import "CollectionView.h"

    @implementation CollectionView

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 100;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Story_Cell_Small";
Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
    }

    @end
```

Yet the app still uses absurd amounts of data upon scrolling. When I opened the storyboard view for the cell and removed all the views in the cell and again measured my apps memory usage in Instruments there was no memory usage upon scrolling through the empty cells. I could see that were in fact cells based on the scroll bar moving.

So the point is that the views in the cells are using up huge amounts of memory without me doing anything accept placing them in the cell in the apps storyboard.

My question is then, how can I fix this? Am I doing something absurdly wrong?

Comment: 3 rows is how many cells? Is memory your only concern, or is it sluggish when scrolling?

Comment: I meant cells when I said rows, sorry. I have paging enabled and scrolling is perfectly smooth unless I try to scroll as fast as I possibly can and even still it's not too bad. It's really just the memory that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the images in your cells?  Images are what eat memory up.  How are you loading the images?  Using `imageNamed:` will cache the images in memory.  If you use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, this will not cache the contents.

Comment: I'm actually loading them via background image loading code called EGOImageLoader. That's not the problem though because when I remove the just the image and the code for the image minuscule amounts of memory are saved.